# Format a number 1000 as 1k, 1000000 as 1m etc. in R

Tags: r, number-formatting

I need to display numbers using abbreviations like so

```
1 shows as 1
999 shows as 999
1000 shows as 1K
999000 shows as 999K
1000000 shows as 1M
1500000 shows as 1.5M
1000000000 shows as 1G
etc...
```

I have seen the question asked all over stackoverflow for other languages (at least thrice for Javascript):

[Format a javascript number with a Metric Prefix like 1.5K, 1M, 1G, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633462/format-a-javascript-number-with-a-metric-prefix-like-1-5k-1m-1g-etc)

[Format a number as 2.5K if a thousand or more, otherwise 900](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461621/format-a-number-as-2-5k-if-a-thousand-or-more-otherwise-900)

[How to format numbers similar to Stack Overflow reputation format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177855/how-to-format-numbers-similar-to-stack-overflow-reputation-format)

[1000000 to 1M and 1000 to 1K in oracle query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522582/1000000-to-1m-and-1000-to-1k-in-oracle-query)

[1000 to 1k, 1000000 to 1m etc. number abbreviation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154351/1000-to-1k-1000000-to-1m-etc-number-abbreviation)

...but I was unable to find anything for R. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `dplyr::case_when`:

```
so_formatter <- function(x) {
  dplyr::case_when(
      x < 1e3 ~ as.character(x),
      x < 1e6 ~ paste0(as.character(x/1e3), "K"),
      x < 1e9 ~ paste0(as.character(x/1e6), "M"),
      TRUE ~ "To be implemented..."
  )
}

test <- c(1, 999, 1000, 999000, 1000000, 1500000, 1000000000, 100000000000)
so_formatter(test)


# [1] "1"                   
# [2] "999"                 
# [3] "1K"                  
# [4] "999K"                
# [5] "1M"                  
# [6] "1.5M"                
# [7] "To be implemented..."
# [8] "To be implemented..."
```

Comment: Your answer is cleaner than those in the recomendation @akrun used to mark the question as duplicate.

Comment: @phiver I understand that aspect, and I am just letting him  know what I think, beyond that, posting his answer in the original question is up to him.